# Xamarin Timer is not Running as long as it says

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, timer

I have this code

```
Color[] colours = new Color[5]{Color.Red, Color.Blue, Color.Green, Color.Yellow, Color.Black};


    public int randGen(int lower, int upper)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        return random.Next(lower, upper);
    }

    public PlayGame()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        changeColour();
    }

    public void changeColour()
    {
        int milliseconds = randGen(1000, 5000);
        int count = 0;
        Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(milliseconds), () =>
        {
            var layout = new StackLayout { Padding = new Thickness(5, 10) };
            var label = new Label { Text = "Time: ", TextColor = Color.Green, FontSize = 25 };
            layout.Children.Add(label);

            label.Text += milliseconds.ToString();
            this.Content = layout;

            if (count < 4)
            {
                BackgroundColor = colours[count];
                count++;

                milliseconds = randGen(1000, 5000);
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                BackgroundColor = Color.Black;
                return false;
            }

        }
        );

    }
```

Which has an array of colours. The idea is that every 1-5 seconds (which should be random each time), the background colour should change, and the text should write how long the screen was on for.

Currently, however, the time shown in the text is not reflective of the time each screen shows for, and I have some speculative concern that milliseconds in:

```
Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(milliseconds)
```

doesn't change at all. Any ideas?

Comment: `Device.StartTimer` uses the device's alarm capabilities, may be your device can only rise an alarm in interval of n seconds. Try to use an async task in loop instead of a timer.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to using Xamarin. What exactly _is_ an async task / could you direct me to any resources

Comment: changing the value of `milliseconds` after the Timer has already started will not do anything

Comment: @Jason that's what I suspected - any idea how to fix it?

Comment: use System.Timers instead, and if you want to change the interval once the timer is started, you will (I believe) need to stop it first.  OR - you can have the timer fire at a fixed interval, and maintain an internal counter that only allows the code to execute when it reaches a threshhold

Comment: @Jason beware with `Systems.Timers.Timer`, it runs in it's own thread so you will need to invoke the interactions with the UI.

Answer (score 1):

this is what I would do - have your timer fire every second (or whatever granularity you need) but only execute your code every X times

```
using System.Timers;

// these are class variables
Timer timer;
int timecount = 0;
// adjust this dynamically so your code only executes every 1-n seconds
int interval = 1;

// to this wherever you want to start the timer
timer = new Timer();
timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
// fire every 1 sec
timer.Interval = 1000;
timer.Start();

// timer event handler
private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    timecount++;

    if (timecount == interval)
    {
      timecount = 0;

      // do other stuff here
    }
}
```

Comment: So you are saying I need a seperate timer class (for lines 4-7 of your answer?)

Comment: that is a System.Timers.Timer, as opposed to using Device.StartTimer

Comment: So it's all part of the same function?

Comment: the first block are class variables.  The 2nd block goes in whatever method you use to start the timer - in your case, OnAppearing.  The 3rd block is an event handler.

Comment: I'm still having problems. I have put the first block of code where I declare a Timer timer, interval etc alongside my array of colours at the top of my code. In OnAppearing(), I've added your code, and where you say `//do other stuff here` I have written: `BackgroundColor = colours[index]; index++` where index is the global variable of position in colours array. However, it still only shows the background to be the first colour of the array. What have I done wrong?

Comment: you possibly need to force the update on the UI thread, use the MainThread class in Xamarin Essentials